# Number of resque workers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redis, resque

How many workers are initialized by default in Resque queues when the following command is executed?

```
QUEUE=(QUEUE NAME) rake environment resque:work
```

Answer (score 4):

`rake resque:work` starts exactly one worker. If you want to start multiple workers (for example four workers) you need to run:

```
COUNT=4 rake resque:workers
```

When you start `resque:workers` without a `COUNT` or with a `COUNT` of `0` then no workers will be started.

You might want to have a look at the implementation of the [`resque's rake tasks`](https://github.com/resque/resque/blob/5379faa08db53233d7a1bbc4f1e01104be7d7851/lib/resque/tasks.rb).

Comment: @shantanoo: I fixed the link in my answer.